# Does the HTML <base> tag have to be in the head?

Tags: html

Looking through [this guide](http://www.htmldog.com/references/html/tags/base/) on using the HTML `<base>` tag, it says:

> If used, the base element must be placed inside the head element and it should only be used once.

However, I've used `<base>` in places that were NOT the head, and it appeared to work without a problem.  Is this more a style guideline, or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: For IE it must be in head https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535191(v=vs.85).aspx ("Remarks" section on the bottom of page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When present, the BASE element must appear in the HEAD section of an HTML document, before any element that refers to an external source.

From the [HTML4 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.4). Similarly worded in the [specs of HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-base-element)

It may be that browsers don't ignore `<base>` placed somewhere else in a page. It is quite common that browser are tolerant to possible deviations from specifications

Answer (score 0):

It does seem to be part of the 'metadata' family, which should always reside in the `<head>`

> Contexts in which this element can be used:
>       In a head element containing no other base elements.

Here's some official documentation regarding the `<base>` element:

https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/base

Answer (score 0):

Always check the current documentation, [read the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-base-element)

> Contexts in which this element can be used: In a head element
>   containing no other base elements.

Browsers are required to do the best they can with invalid markup, such as placing this outside the head element. That's why you can get it to work but it would still be invalid. You should never rely on invalid markup working at all or from one browser to the next.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR—Concerning specification, `base` elements must be placed in context of a `head` element.

---

Both [WHATWG Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-base-element) and the [W3C Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-base-element) for HTML5 state:

> **Contexts in which this element can be used:**
> In a `head` element containing no other `base` elements.

As a document metadata, it makes sense to have it in the head of the document. Regardless of specification however, browsers will “auto-correct” misplaced elements anywhere and evaluate them. Since it’s not particularly clean work and might constitute a source of errors, one should adhere to the specification.